# Sorting names alphabetically using selection sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm doing homework that asks me to sort names alphabetically(both ascending and descending order) using selection sort. So there is a data file that has all the names saved in it and it's called "names.dat". 
The names are saved like:

```
Collins, Bill
Smith, Bart
.
.
.
Holland, Beth
```

So what I did was reading the data from the file and saved them in a 2D array. Then I wrote a void function that sorts the names in the ascending order. I think I understand how the selection sort method works, but I don't seem to understand how to work the 2D array around... Eventually i need to display the first names sorted alphabetically without sorting last names (and I'm just going to assume that the names are saved in the form of "first, last") so for example, after sorting the display will look like : "Collins, Bill /n Holland, Beth /n, ..., Smith, Bart"

It took me many hours to understand the selection sort and write it in the program, but now I'm facing the issue of not knowing how to manipulate the array... I would really appreciate your help! I will post my program here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;
void setAscendingSort(string [][], int);
//void setDescendingSort();
void displayArray(string [][]);

int main()
{
    string first, last, NAMES[SIZE][2];

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("names.dat");

    int i = 0;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> first;
        NAMES[i][0] = first;
        cout << NAMES[i][0] << " ";

        if(infile.eof())
        {
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

        infile >> last;
        NAMES[i][1] = last;
        cout << NAMES[i][1] << " " << endl;
        ++i;
    }

    setAscendingSort(NAMES, SIZE);
    cout << "The volues after the selection sort is performed are:" << endl;
    displayArray(NAMES, SIZE);

    return 0;

}

void displayArray(int array[][], int elems)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < elems; count++)
        cout << array[count][0] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void setAscendingSort(string array[][], int elems)
{
    int seek = 0;
    int minCount; //location of smallest value found
    int minValue; //holds the smallest value found

    for (seek = 0; seek < (elems - 1); seek++)
    {
        minCount = seek;
        minValue = array[seek][0];

        for (int index = seek + 1; index < elems; index++)
        {
            if (array[index][0] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index][0];
                minCount = index;
            }
        }

        array[minCount][0] = array[seek];
        array[seek] = minValue;
    }
}
```

I mean when I wrote it, it completely made sense to me but I'm a novice to programming after all. :(

Comment: I would suggest using a vector<string> instead of a 2-dim array to store the names. Treat "<first name>, <last name>" as one string. Now your list of names will be like a 1-dim array. Makes your job much more easier and meets the requirements still. You could implement a selection sort algorithm on this. I am however assuming that your teacher has covered vectors and is ok with them being used for this homework.

Comment: So like#include<deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::string> names;
    std::ifstream infile("names.dat");
    std::string name;
    while(getline(infile, name))
        names.push_back(name);
    return 0;
}
??

Comment: And note: [this : `while (!infile.eof())` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @WhozCraig Someone pointed out too but I didn't quite understand why it was wrong.. even my book said while(!infile.eof()) ?

Comment: Burn the book, and read the link provided in my comment, in particular the *first* answer. Regarding the problem. first consider what each string *pair* represents. A *person*. You may do well to consider using a `struct` or `class` with two members (first and last as `std::string`) and a 1D array of *that* rather than a 2D array and trying to manage independent columns and keeping them in sync. Using a 2D array is doable, just more work than it needs to be.

Comment: @weathergirl - Yes that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @user3493289 okay so I edited the part of the program so the data are now all saved in vector. And no, my professor hasn't covered vectors yet... And now i just don't know how to go from here..